# JavaScript: Always return .toFixed(2) from a function (currency support)

Tags: javascript, node.js, floating-point, numbers, currency

Is there a way in Node/JavaScript to signal that a variable should always be returned with `.toFixed(2)`. I.E. a currency type.

See the following example function:

```
let PER_SHARE_COMMISSION = 0.005; // USD
let MINIMUM_COMMISSION_PER_ORDER = 1.00; // USD
let MAXIMUM_PERCENT_OF_ORDER = 0.005; // 0.5%

exports.commission = function(price, shares) {
    let commish = shares * PER_SHARE_COMMISSION;

    if(commish < MINIMUM_COMMISSION_PER_ORDER) {
        return MINIMUM_COMMISSION_PER_ORDER.toFixed(2);
    }

    var maxCommish = shares * price * MAXIMUM_PERCENT_OF_ORDER;
    if(commish > maxCommish) {
        return maxCommish.toFixed(2);
    }

    return commish.toFixed(2);
};
```

See how I have to manually put `.toFixed(2)` anywhere before returning the value. This is error prone. Is there a pattern around this?

Comment: You *could* create a wrapping function.. or alter the function such that there is only one `return` point. I'm not so sure that I would call either of those 'patterns'. Depending on how this function is used, it may be more appropriate to use a *downstream filter*: eg. the UI control (or one of the various framework bindings) displays/maps the appropriate currency representation. (The contract should probably be that the commission function would still return a value round appropriately per the currency resolution.)

Comment: there is no concept of a functions "return type" in javascript, so, no

Answer (score 0):

Here is basically the solution I am looking for:

```
currency(1) // "1.00"
currency(23.3433) // "23.34"
currency(87.3987) // "87.40"
currency(12342.453) // "12342.45"

function currency(input) {
    return new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
        style: 'decimal',
        currency: 'USD',
        minimumFractionDigits: 2,
        maximumFractionDigits: 2,
        useGrouping: false
    }).format(input);
}
```

Comment: it can't be number, because number does not keep tail zero in floating , (same as it not keeps leading zeros in integer part)

Comment: If this isn't the answer to your question you shouldn't post it as "Answer". You could edit your original question to include this information in order to make your question more precise. Or remove the "but..." remark, mark this as the Answer, then post the "but..." as a new question.